# Product rule trig

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates, products

This was given as a solution to a question and I've tried working it out but can never get the same answer. Here $x=rcosϕ$ and $y=rsinϕ$

[image]

It's mostly the first 2 lines I don't understand. Wouldn't $x^2 = r^2cos^2ϕ$ and $y^2 = r^2sin^2ϕ$? And how did the first 2 terms of the second line come along? I can understand the last 2 terms from the product rule but not the beginning...

Comment: $x^2 = r^2\cos^2\phi = (r\cos \phi)^2 = r\cos \phi \cdot r\cos \phi$

Comment: Yes I know :) but I usually write it as $r^2cos^2ϕ$ so I'm just wondering if this way of writing it works as well but apparently not as it needs to be written $rcosϕ*rcosϕ$

Comment: In the second line, they're replacing one $r\cos \phi $ by $x$ :   $$\begin{align}r\cos \phi \cdot r\cos\phi d\phi &=   x \cdot  r\cos\phi d\phi \\ &= x\left[d(r\sin \phi) - \sin\phi dr\right] \\&= xdy - x\sin\phi dr\\&= xdy - r\cos\phi\sin\phi dr\end{align}$$

Comment: similar thing happens to the other term from first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ r^2d\phi=r^2\cdot1\cdot d\phi=r^2\cdot(\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi))\cdot d\phi=$$

$$\ =r^2\cos^2(\phi)d\phi+r^2\sin^2(\phi)d\phi=r\cos(\phi) r\cos(\phi)d\phi+r\cos(\phi) r\cos(\phi)d\phi$$

Now you have that:

$$\ r\cos(\phi)=x$$

and

$$d(r\sin(\phi))=\sin(\phi)dr+rd(\sin(\phi))=\sin(\phi)dr+r\cos(\phi)d\phi$$

$$d(r\cos(\phi))=\cos(\phi)dr-r\sin(\phi)d\phi$$

so you get

$$\ r\cos(\phi)d\phi=d(r\sin(\phi))-\sin(\phi)dr$$

$$\ r\sin(\phi)d\phi=\cos(\phi)dr-d(r\cos(\phi))$$

Comment: just a quick question, what if it was $r^2dϕ^2$? what changes?

Comment: well, I suppose you should express $\ d\phi$ in terms of x and y in the final result.